# How to detect iOS device appearance update in a variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-darkmode

I have a String `deviceColorScheme` that gets it's value from variable `colorScheme` that detects what appearance the device is set to. It works until the device's appearance is switched in settings or control centre  and `colorScheme` doesn't update.

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
let deviceColorScheme: String = "\(colorScheme)"
```

My question is - can I detect this change? And if I can, how?

Comment: Where are you checking value for deviceColorScheme?

Comment: Your `colorScheme` is updated when device color scheme is updated, you don't need additional `deviceColorScheme`, use `colorScheme` where needed.

Answer (score 3):

var isDark = false

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *)
{
isDark = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? true : false
}

override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        isDark = previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? true : false
    } else {
        print("Light")
        isDark = false
    }
}
```